# How to add ngbDropdown to bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I use ng-bootstrap  Angular 2.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse"> 
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">  
           <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
           </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <div ngbDropdown>
                  <button class="btn" ngbDropdownToggle>Projects</button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <button class="dropdown-item"  >AA</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
```

The problems "dropdown-menu" could not be expanded

Comment: are you missing the link to bootstrap in you index.html? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: add ngbDropDownMenu for dropdown-menu element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to see what is going on in your particular project as I've just did copy & paste of your code and it works perfectly fine, check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/CFntB5mkshJ97x1aIGU1?p=preview

You might want to verify if you properly importing (`import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'`) adding the `NgbModule` module:

`@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, NgbModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}`

Comment: It is not working. In plunker also you added stylesheet link of bootstrap 4. Why is it needed when you are installing bootstrap module ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this for bootstrap 5.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your App</a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>

    <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
    <li ngbDropdown class="nav-item">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        id="dropdownMenu"
        ngbDropdownToggle
      >
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <a ngbDropdownItem href="#">Item 1</a>
        <a ngbDropdownItem href="#">Item 2</a>
        <a ngbDropdownItem href="#">Item 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your navbar toggleable, check this out;

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse">
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navExample" aria-controls="navExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    &#9776;
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="navExample">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">First link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Second link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you want just a dropdown menu in your navigation bar, example in official site should work;

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Be sure your html file include bootstrap (I use bootstrap 4).

Comment: This kinda solves my problem, but I thought the whole point of using `ng-bootstrap` was that you didn't have to include jQuery...